# Simple Q&A consoleapp problems

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm at a very beginner level of programming, so be patient to me. I'd like to make a very simple console application, which contains a question at the beginning, and the answer for that question determines the programs reaction. The question at the beginning is "What's your name?", and if I answer "John", it shall say: "You are a mean guy", and any other answers beside "John" leads to the reaction :"You are a nice guy". (It shall be a joke to my friend).

Here is my code so far:

```
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s;
        Boolean b;


        Console.WriteLine("Hogy hívnak?");
        b = Console.ReadLine();
        s = Convert.ToBoolean();

        if (b = "Zsolt") 
            Console.WriteLine("You are a mean guy :(((");

        else Console.WriteLine("You are a nice guy! :)))))");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

For you guys it must be obvious, but my problem is, that I get an error message, which says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'".

So my question is: what have I did wrong? What did I miss? I should convert my string into what, to make it work?

Thanks for the answers, and sorry for bothering you guys with this, but I seek knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a `boolean` variable `b`.  `==` tests whether two objects are equal; `=` assigns the value of one object to a variable.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s;

    Console.WriteLine("Hogy hívnak?");
    s = Console.ReadLine();

    if (s == "Zsolt") 
        Console.WriteLine("You are a mean guy :(((");
    else 
        Console.WriteLine("You are a nice guy! :)))))");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Boolean, only a condition which yields a Boolean:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s;


    Console.WriteLine("Hogy hívnak?");
    s = Console.ReadLine();

    if (s == "Zsolt") 
        Console.WriteLine("You are a mean guy :(((");

    else Console.WriteLine("You are a nice guy! :)))))");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```